# Generating multiple statement code using lisp macro

Tags: macros, lisp

As per my understanding one of the usage of macro in LISP is to generate desired code.

I have following main body code:

```
(list (list "aVar" "Hi")
      (list "bVar" 10)
      (list "addSW1" (equal dpl->addSW1)) 
      ...
      (list "addSW100" (equal dpl->addSW100)))
```

So, basically I am trying to write macros that generate code for `SW1` to `SW100` so that I dont need to write 100 lines.

I created my 1st macro:

```
(defmacro myMac1 (dpl sw)
 `(list ,switchStr "boolean" (equal "Y" (get ,dpl ,sw))))
```

That worked for me and so I can now do `(myMac1 "addSW1")` that will generate single list statement.

Then, I created 2nd mac:

```
(defmacro myMac2 (dpl @rest allSwitches)
 `(mapcar (lambda (sw)
            (myMac1 ,dpl sw))
          ,@allSwitches))
```

So, if I write `(myMac2 dpl "addSW1" "addSW2" ... "addSW100")`
It will generate:

```
(list (list "addSW1" (equal dpl->addSW1)) 
      ... till 100))
```

But, in main body code I don't want list of list. I just wanted 100 lists.

Any solution? Sorry for very long description :P.

Answer (score 3):

You have to understand the difference between compile time and evaluation time.

The macro is expanded at compile time and everything, that is quoted, is inserted into the source code as is (without evaluation). So `(macroexpand-1 '(myMac2 1 2 3))` will yield `(mapcar (lambda (sw) (myMac2 1 sw)) 2 3)` (Also note, that you have to use `&rest` in place of `@rest`.

If you want to get the *result* of `mapcar`, that form shouldn't be quoted:

```
(defmacro myMac2 (dpl &rest allSwitches)
  (mapcar (lambda (sw)
            `(myMac1 ,dpl ,sw))
          allSwitches))
(macroexpand-1 '(myMac2 1 2 3)) => ((myMac1 1 2) (myMac1 1 3))
```

But this isn't a valid form. What you want is `(list (myMac1 1 2) (myMac1 1 3))`. To achieve that you have to wrap `list` around the generated forms (why you should use `,@` here is left as an exercise for though ;)

```
(defmacro myMac2 (dpl &rest allSwitches)
  `(list ,@(mapcar (lambda (sw)
                    `(myMac1 ,dpl ,sw))
                   allSwitches)))
(macroexpand-1 '(myMac2 1 2 3)) => (list (myMac1 1 2) (myMac1 1 3))
```

Comment: Thanks for helping in this. As I am calling this macro from list, I want (myMac1 1 2) (myMac1 1 3) as my final solution, but not the list of them. 2nd solution given produces list of two myMac1. Is it possible to get only (myMac1 1 2) (myMac1 1 3).

Comment: I also tried your first solution, but got error: *Error* eval: not a function - (mymac1 1 2).

Comment: By the way, this is scheme dialect. Cadence SKILL .

Comment: Here it doesn't matter a lot, if it's Lisp or Scheme. Answering your question about getting `(myMac1 1 2) (myMac1 1 3)`: 1 macro can produce 1 item (either atom, list, or other object). You can't technically get 2 items, but you can nest them in a special operator, which is called `progn` in Lisp and `begin` in Scheme. This is where `,@` is needed: it takes a list (output of a macro) and 'splices' it into the wrapper form. But there should be a wrapper form, that in you case will be `begin`. But note, that this way you'll loose all the results of calling `list`, but the last one.